# FactoryGirl: Building an object creates its associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I don't know if this is a bug with FactoryGirl or if it is something i am doing wrong

I have two factory definitions

```
factory :employee do
  name "name1"
  association :department
end

factory :department do
  name "department1"
end
```

I would expect the following to build both employee and department

```
FactoryGirl.build(:employee, :name => "employee")
```

But it builds the employee object and creates department in the database. I am sure it use to work in some older versions of FactoryGirl.

I am using factory_girl version 4.2.0.

How do i make it build the associated objects instead of creating one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `build_stubbed`

```
FactoryGirl.build_stubbed :employee
```

Then FactoryGirl will build an employee object and a department object in memory. All of the two have fake ids like 1000+, and correctly associated.

Comment: Is there any other difference between build and build_stubbed except for the id?

Comment: Id is the main difference, and then the usage. `build_stubbed` is stub objects, living in memory but works the same as saved objects. But `build` is almost like an ActiveRecord method though it comes from FactoryGirl. So, if your test is going to build an object, make some changes and then save(say you are testing validation), go through the normal `build` process, but you still need a persisted association object at first as what you saw in question. If you are testing model's methods, `build_stubbed` is good to go.

Comment: `build_stubbed` can't be used on controller tests or integration tests which use different instances and then require fully persisted objects -- use `create` in those cases.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is the default behaviour for FactoryGirl. However, the documentation shows you that you can specify a build strategy for your association, e.g.:

```
factory :employee do
  name "name1"
  association :department, strategy: :build
end
```

See https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations

Comment: This builds the associated object if i create the main object. What i want is the associated objects to build when i build the main and create when i create the main

Comment: You could maybe use a hook to do that, along these lines:

`after(:create) {|employee| employee.department.save! }`

It's not something I've done regularly though, so do check that this works for you.

Comment: In my hands, and per https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/64, @Vimsha's statement is not correct and there is no need for a hook. `strategy: :build` actually creates if the parent is being created (and stubs if the parent is being stubbed). So you can set all of your `belongs_to` and `has_one` associations to `strategy: :build` and factory_girl will always do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful because build won't save the object, but if the factory has associations it will still make requests to a database. For example, if you defined association in department factory they will be persisted in db. build_stubbed, on the other hand, will create associations via build_stubbed too.

Read more about this topic [here](https://kolosek.com/factory-girl-build-vs-build_stub)