# Specify a FactoryGirl association that builds not creates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

I have two models that have `has_one` relationship:

```
class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :location, as: :locatable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location, allow_destroy: true
  ...
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :locatable, polymorphic: true
  ...
end
```

My `entity` factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :entity do
    association :location
    ...
  end
end
```

When I want to `build` an Entity, FactoryGirl creates the location:

```
> e = FactoryGirl.build(:entity)
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `locations` (`address`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('New York, NY, US', '2014-07-28 19:04:10', '2014-07-28 19:04:10')
=> #<Entity id: nil, name: "Foobar", ..., created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Other than:

```
  before(:each) do
    @entity = Factory.build(:entity)
    @location = Factory.build(:location, :entity => @entity)
  end
```

Is there a way to instruct FactoryGirl to `build` the Location when the Entity is built and `create` the Location when the Entity is created?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407234/factorygirl-building-an-object-creates-its-associated-object

Answer (score 0):

Either `build_stubbed` or `attributes_for` will get you want you want. Try:

```
  before(:each) do
    @entity = Factory.attributes_for(:entity)
    @location = Factory.build(:location, :entity => @entity)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple change to the factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :entity do
    association :location, strategy: :build
    ...
  end
end
```